# Using Carbon to convert a date to another format

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I Have a date thats 12/1/2018 and i want to switch it to 2018/12/01 and im using carbon but im unsure on how to do this.

I've tried using the parse method and carbon seems to confuse me and i get random errors.

Answer (score 8):

solved it, i used:

```
Carbon::parse($input)->format('Y-m-d'); // converts MM/DD/YYYY to YYYY/MM/DD
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
Carbon::parse('12/1/2018')->format('Y/m/d');
```